# Looping audio with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

For my audio project I need to create a looping function. for this example the looping time is from 3 seconds to 8 seconds.

**What I expect**

On clicking on the `loop-icon` before the 8 second mark I'd expect the audio to begin looping indefinitely once the 8 second mark is passed.

On clicking the `loop-icon` after the 8 second mark the audio should immediately loop indefinitely between 3 and 8 seconds.

On clicking the `loop-icon` a second time the looping stops and the audio continues playing as usual.

**What is happening**

On clicking on the `loop-icon` before the 8 second mark the audio keeps playing as usual with no loop ever being executed after the 8 second mark is passed.

On clicking on the `loop-icon` after the 8 second mark causes the loop but only once and the audio plays as usual without ever looping a second time.

On clicking the `loop-icon` a second time does the same as the above problems.

```js
const audio = document.querySelector('.audio');
const loopIcon = document.querySelector('.loop-icon');

let loopOn = false;

loopIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (loopOn === false) {
    loopOn = true;
    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeLoop());
  } else {
    loopOn = false;
    audio.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeLoop());
  }
});

function timeLoop() {
  if (audio.currentTime >= 8) {
    audio.currentTime = 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<i class="fas fa-redo-alt loop-icon"></i>
<audio class="audio" src="https://radio.pastemagazine.com/audio/320/2146615065.mp3" controls>
</audio>
```

Comment: @Kaiido I wasn't even aware of this concept. Because of your link, I got my code to work. Thank you.